# QGIS UTM zones - TIN interpolation plugin

Tags: qgis, utm

I am trying to add a Z-variable to a vector in order to eventually calculate the volume or the zone using TIN. I was told I first need to set my UTM in order for my Z-variable to be recognized in meters. If my vector spans accross various UTM zones, which ones do I use?